# I keep losing my Swype keyboard

Tags: motorola-droid, keyboard, cyanogenmod, swype

I'm running CM6 on a Motorola Droid.

Every now and then (at least once a day), my keyboard will revert from Swype back to the Stock Android Keyboard and I have switch back to the Swype keyboard to be able to use it again.

And sometimes (at least once every other day), the Swype keyboard will be completely disabled and I have to go back into Settings --> Keyboards and re-enable Swype.

This is starting to get really annoying.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you try other alternative keyboard? Do you lose them as well or is it just Swype?

Comment: @Lie Good suggestion, I'll try that

Comment: I've not seen this behavior. Then again, it IS a beta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this problem was caused by having Swype installed to the SD card.  Moving Swype back to the phone's internal storage seems to have fixed the problem.

```
Settings-->Applications-->Manage Applications-->Swype-->Select "move to phone"
```

Comment: It's so irritating to see the OS differentiating between storage locations.

Comment: I want to be able to install anywhere, always.

Answer (score 1):

Good question... I'm experiencing this currently although the app is already living on my phone. A quick fix for me seems to be un-selecting Swype as the alternative keyboard (see steps below) and then re-selecting it. Then I will then have to reset Swype (i.e. long-press in a text field, select Input Method and select Swype).

```
Settings > Language & Keyboard > Swype
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion: is it possible that you have Swype on the kill list in your task killer?

(NOTE: I have a Droid as well, and have not experienced this. I do not run a task killer though. Also, I could not live without Swype.)

Comment: No, I do not run a task killer.

Answer (score 0):

Try relicensing it.  That has worked for me in the past.